# How to store column data as comma separated values when finding duplicate values in another column?

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, merge

I must combine or implode subarray values if the product will be the same for any company.

Expected output should be like:

```
0 => 
array (
    'company' => '1,6'
    'product' => 5,
),
```

My Array is:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'company' => 1,
        'product' => 5,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'company' => 2,
        'product' => 4,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'company' => 6,
        'product' => 5,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
        'company' => 2,
        'product' => 3,
    ),
)
```

My code is:

```
foreach($prSuppliers as $key=>$val){
    if($prSuppliers[$key]['company_master_id']==$val['company_master_id']){
        $contactemaileach = $val['company_master_id'];
        $imp = implode(',', $contactemaileach);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, and what's your question or problem? What's the result of your code? How does it differ from what you want? Also, what you claim is the "expected output" is not a valid array.

Comment: I presume that `$prSuppliers[$key]['company_master_id']==$val['company_master_id']` is __always__ true.

Comment: Is suppose expected output is: `'company' => 1,6`?

Comment: @Michel yes I right. I corrected the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`implode()` is not going to be part of a simple/direct solution.  You should assign temporary keys using the product values so that you can determine, during each iteration, if you are dealing with the first occurrence (store the whole subarray) or a subsequent occurrence of a product (append/concatenate the new company value using a comma as glue).

When finished iterating, re-index the array with `array_values()`.

Code: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/X718h)

```
$array = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'company' => 1,
        'product' => 5,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'company' => 2,
        'product' => 4,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'company' => 6,
        'product' => 5,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
        'company' => 2,
        'product' => 3,
    ),
);

foreach ($array as $set) {
    if (!isset($result[$set['product']])) {
        $result[$set['product']] = $set;
    } else {
        $result[$set['product']]['company'] .= ",{$set['company']}";
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'company' => '1,6',
    'product' => 5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'company' => 2,
    'product' => 4,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'company' => 2,
    'product' => 3,
  ),
)
```